# Json deserialization problem in c # form & json.net application

Tags: c#, json, .net, visual-studio

I have a field in a table containing json data like this:

```
 [
  {
    "field_name": "text_icona_principale",
    "field_value": "0"
  },
  {
    "field_name": "text_titolo_principale",
    "field_value": "0"
  },
  {
    "field_name": "servizio",
    "field_value": [
      "Video "
    ]
  },
  {
    "field_name": "text_totale_ordine",
    "field_value": "0"
  },
  {
    "field_name": "totale_ordine",
    "field_value": "29.99"
  },
  {
    "field_name": "nome",
    "field_value": "Pinco"
  },
  {
    "field_name": "cognome",
    "field_value": "Panco"
  }
]
```

I have tried in every way to deserialize them using json.net but nothing, errors or null.

Comment: Show the code to deserialize that. Without we can only say that you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `JsonConvert` using `Newtonsoft.Json` Library

```
//Create the modal based on your json
public class KeyValuePair
{
    public string field_name { get; set; }
    public object field_value { get; set; }
}

//Deserialize using JsonConvert
var json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair>>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize your JSON to the `List<Item>` which item is:

```
public class Item
{
  public string field_name { get; set; }
  public object field_value { get; set; } 
}
```

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>('JSON');